# Efficient way to print Q&A?

Tags: support

What I do is copying the Q&A to a Word document, rearrange it as needed (if needed), and then print it. Is this the best way possible? How to easily and efficiently get a printable version?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try an Ad-on for that. There is a Firefox Ad-on called [Print Edit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/print-edit/).

> Allows editing of web page content while in Print Preview mode, prior to printing or saving as HTML or PDF.
>
> *Compacts the layout and removes unwanted content such as adverts, sidebars and blank pages. Any element can be formatted, hidden or deleted.*

I've just tried it for couple of Q+As on DA. It's working good.